# How to set cursor position in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

There are two `EditText`,while loading the page a text is set in the first EditText, So now cursor will be in the starting place of `EditText`, I want to **set cursor position in the second EditText** which contains no data. How to do this?

Comment: you can set its gravity to 'center'.it will automatically sets the cursor to be in center. your text would also be centered then.

Comment: first of all, try improving your accept ratio. second, what do you mean by setting cursor position, when there is no text in edittext?

Answer (score 539, accepted):

Where position is an int:

```
editText1.setSelection(position)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this at the XML file?

Comment: @kike I don't think so

Comment: use android:selection in xml with data binding

Answer (score 104):

I have done this way to set cursor position to *end of the text after updating the text of EditText programmatically*
here, `etmsg` is EditText

```
etmsg.setText("Updated Text From another Activity");
int position = etmsg.length();
Editable etext = etmsg.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```

Comment: +1 ah! Nice it helped me to set the cursor position in edittext.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I have Spannable strings in my EditText.  Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @toobsco42 Hello, I have just tried to use Spannable String in edittext.. check this http://pastebin.com/i02ZrNw4 and it is working as expected as it should be.. check and compare

Comment: Can this possible from xml File? @MKJParekh

Comment: Seems to do the same: `etmsg.setText("my new text..."); etmsg.setSelection(etmsg.length());`

Answer (score 48):

### How to Set EditText Cursor position in Android

Below Code is **Set cursor to Starting** in `EditText`:

```
 EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
 editText.setSelection(0);
```

Below Code is **Set cursor to end** of the `EditText`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Below Code is Set cursor after some 2th Character position :

```
 EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
 editText.setSelection(2);
```

Answer (score 23):

> I want to set cursor position in edittext which contains no data

There is only one position in an empty EditText, it's [`setSelection(0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection%28int%29).

Or did you mean you want to get focus to your `EditText` when your activity opens? In that case its  [`requestFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)

Comment: setSelection(0) is not working ,I dont want to get focus to the second EditText,I only want to set the cursor in the second EditText

Comment: If I remember correctly, when an EditText requests focus, the cursor is set. [Read this](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-set-focus-and-show-soft.html)

Answer (score 13):

Let editText2 is your second EditText view .then put following piece of code in **onResume()**

```
editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText2.requestFocus();
```

or put

```
<requestFocus />
```

in your xml layout of the second EditText view.

Answer (score 12):

use the below line

```
e2.setSelection(e2.length());
```

`e2` is edit text Object Name

Answer (score 12):

If you want to place the cursor in a certain position on an EditText, you can use:

```
yourEditText.setSelection(position);
```

Additionally, there is the possibility to set the initial and final position, so that you programmatically select some text, this way:

```
yourEditText.setSelection(startPosition, endPosition);
```

Please note that setting the selection might be tricky since you can place the cursor *before* or *after* a character, the image below explains how to index works in this case:

[image]

So, if you want the cursor at the end of the text, just set it to `yourEditText.length()`.

Answer (score 10):

some time edit text cursor donot comes at particular position is if we directly use `editText.setSelection(position);` .
In that case you can try

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editText.setSelection(string.length());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

`setSelection(int index)` method in `Edittext` should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 4):

as a reminder: if you are using `edittext.setSelection()` to set the cursor, and it is NOT working while setting up an `alertdialog` for example, make sure to set the `selection()` AFTER the dialog has been created

example:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
input.setSelection(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4):

This code will help you to show your cursor at the last position of editing text.

```
 editText.requestFocus();
 editText.setSelection(editText.length());
```

Answer (score 4):

This will move the cursor to end of edittext

`myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().toString().length())`

Answer (score 2):

Remember call `requestFocus()` before `setSelection` for edittext.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
if (your_edittext.getText().length() > 0 ) {

    your_edittext.setSelection(your_edittext.getText().length());
}
```

Can you add this line to your EditText xml

```
android:gravity="right"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"//you set this as you need
```

But when any Text writing you should set the paddingleft to zero

you should use this on addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 1):

> I won't get setSelection() method directly , so i done like below and
>   work like charm

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setText("Updated New Text");
int position = editText.getText().length();
Editable editObj= editText.getText();
Selection.setSelection(editObj, position);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the cursor after `n` character from
right to left then you have to do like this.

```
edittext.setSelection(edittext.length()-n);
```

If edittext's text like

```
version<sub></sub>
```

and you want to move cursor at 6th position from right

Then it will move the cursor at-

```
    version<sub> </sub>
                ^
```

Comment: Probably this will be helpful for Arabic or Hebrew languages/users, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myEditText.isSelected){
    myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.length())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Set cursor to a row and column

You can use the following code to get the position in your EditText that corresponds to a certain row and column. You can then use `editText.setSelection(getIndexFromPos(row, column))` to set the cursor position.
The following calls to the method can be made:

- `getIndexFromPos(x, y)` Go to the column y of line x
- `getIndexFromPos(x, -1)` Go to the last column of line x
- `getIndexFromPos(-1, y)` Go to the column y of last line
- `getIndexFromPos(-1, -1)` Go to the last column of the last line

All line and column bounds are handled; Entering a column greater than the line's length will return position at the last column of the line. Entering a line greater than the EditText's line count will go to the last line. It should be reliable enough as it was heavily tested.

```
static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

int getIndexFromPos(int line, int column) {
    int lineCount = getTrueLineCount();
    if (line < 0) line = getLayout().getLineForOffset(getSelectionStart());  // No line, take current line
    if (line >= lineCount) line = lineCount - 1;  // Line out of bounds, take last line

    String content = getText().toString() + LINE_SEPARATOR;
    int currentLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
        if (currentLine == line) {
            int lineLength = content.substring(i, content.length()).indexOf(LINE_SEPARATOR);
            if (column < 0 || column > lineLength) return i + lineLength;  // No column or column out of bounds, take last column
            else return i + column;
        }
        if (String.valueOf(content.charAt(i)).equals(LINE_SEPARATOR)) currentLine++;
    }
    return -1;  // Should not happen
}

// Fast alternative to StringUtils.countMatches(getText().toString(), LINE_SEPARATOR) + 1
public int getTrueLineCount() {
    int count;
    String text = getText().toString();
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(text);
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(sr);
    try {
        lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        count = lnr.getLineNumber() + 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        count = 0;  // Should not happen
    }
    sr.close();
    return count;
}
```

The question was already answered but I thought someone could want to do that instead.

It works by looping through each character, incrementing the line count every time it finds a line separator. When the line count equals the desired line, it returns the current index + the column, or the line end index if column is out of bounds. You can also reuse the `getTrueLineCount()` method, it returns a line count ignoring text wrapping, unlike `TextView.getLineCount()`.

Comment: This code seems very useful for multilineEditText developers, but I couldn't apply this code. You mentioned x and y but defined line and column, though, editText.setSelection(getIndexFromPos(getTrueLineCount(), getTrueLineCount())); this seems not working and not calling the function. So, how can we use your code?

Comment: @Bay It's been a long time since I've written this answer, and I had just begun android development at the time. But the principle seems simple enough that you should be able to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, you could create an extension function like this:

```
fun EditText.placeCursorAtLast() {
    val string = this.text.toString()
    this.setSelection(string.length)
}
```

and then simply call `myEditText.placeCursorAtLast()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set cursor position in EditText? try these below code

```
EditText rename;
 String title = "title_goes_here";
 int counts = (int) title.length();
 rename.setSelection(counts);
 rename.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

How to resolve the cursor position issue which is automatically moving to the last position after formatting in US Mobile like (xxx) xxx-xxxx in Android.

```
private String oldText = "";
private int lastCursor;
private EditText mEtPhone;

@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
String cleanString = AppUtil.cleanPhone(s.toString());

String format = cleanString.length() < 11 ? cleanString.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1) $2-$3") :
                cleanString.substring(0, 10).replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1) $2-$3");


boolean isDeleted = format.length() < oldText.length();

        try {

            int cur = AppUtil.getPointer(lastCursor, isDeleted ? s.toString() : format, oldText, isDeleted);
            mEtPhone.setSelection(cur > 0 ? cur : format.length());

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            mEtPhone.setSelection(format.length());
        }

        mEtPhone.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        oldText = s.toString();
        lastCursor = start;
    }
```

Define the below method to any Activityclass in my case Activity name is AppUtil and access it globally

```
public static int getPointer(int index, String newString, String oldText, boolean isDeleted){

        int diff = Math.abs(newString.length() - oldText.length());

        return diff > 1 ? isDeleted ? index - diff : index  + diff : isDeleted ? index : index + 1;
    }

public static String cleanPhone(String phone){

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
            return "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c : phone.toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
                sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And if you want to set any specific position

```
edittext.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way to get cursor position using Kotlin:**

```
val edInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextInput)

var cursorPosition:Int = edInput.selectionStart
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody stuck with caret dropping to the first position each time new symbol is added to an input field... You should save the selection before text is set to your `EditText` and right after setting - set selection back:

```
binding.editName.apply {
     val currentSelection = if (isFocused) selectionEnd else 0
     setText(item.name)
     setSelection(currentSelection)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm so late to answer this problem, so I figure it out. Just use,

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: They want to set the cursor position not the position of the text inside the edittext

Answer (score -4):

I believe the most simple way to do this is just use padding.

Say in your xml's edittext section, add 
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
This will move your start position of cursor 100dp right from left end.

Same way, you can use
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
This will move your end position of cursor 100dp left from right end.

For more detail, check this article *on my blog*: [Android: Setting Cursor Starting and Ending Position in EditText Widget](http://www.arthurwang.net/arthur-wang/android/android-setting-cursor-starting-and-ending-position-in-edittext-widget/)

Comment: Padding has nothing to do with cursor position, and is a completely wrong school of thought in this particular situation.