# Cursor behind the hint

Tags: android, cursor, textview, hint

I have a problem with an `EditText` where gravity is set to center. Because of that I had to put the attribute `android:ellipsize="start"` for the hint to appear in the center.

However, the hint appears before the cursor, which gives a rather ugly appearance to the application:

[image]

What I want to do is display the cursor before the text. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I think there's something else going on here. Could you add the xml for the layout?

Comment: Would it be ok to just clear the hint when the textfield is selected?

Comment: EditText with ellipsize start, and gravity center displays the cursor before the hint. I don't know what you're doing. Btw image's broken.

Comment: Please add the xml file too..

Comment: you can try changing hint text color might be that help you to get any other idea

Comment: If gravity is set to center it doesn't make sense for the cursor to appear on the left hand side of the hint text. Imagine what would happen once you start typing? The text would appear in the center, ie, at a different location than the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 solution，infact that are 2 way.One side when text is empty that need to dispay hint,we hide the hint either show,Another side is adjust cursor(widgit) location.precondition is EditText put in a layout,adjust edittext's layout gravity not it's self gravity.But my demand is before hint,you just gravity to right.
like this pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StmuU.png)

```
 @Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    adjustCursorPosition(etInput.getText());
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    adjustCursorPosition(etInput.getText());
}

private void adjustCursorPosition(CharSequence text){
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etInput.getHint())){
        adjustGravityForCursor(text);
        //adjustCursorVisible(text);
        //adjustHintContent(hasFocus(),text);
    }
}

private void adjustHintContent(boolean hasFocus, CharSequence text){
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        etInput.setHint(hasFocus ? "" : mHint);
    }
}

private void adjustCursorVisible(CharSequence text){
    etInput.setCursorVisible(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text));
}

private void adjustGravityForCursor(CharSequence text) {
    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) etInput.getLayoutParams();
    if (mSpaceWidth <= 0) mSpaceWidth = lp.width;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        etInput.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lp.leftMargin = 0;
    } else {
        etInput.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        lp.leftMargin = (mSpaceWidth - measureText(etInput,mHint)) / 2;
    }
    etInput.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29) method of the EditText, as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext).

Comment: Yes, is still in the centes, because the edittext is empty the only value for the position is "0"

Comment: It is hint not text so it will not work it is problem has occurred due to gravity of hint android:gravity="center" so it will automatically set it any other idea for that ???

Answer (score -1):

The quickest solution will be to clear hint on editText Touch: (I have assumed this edittext to be MYET).
First, set an onTouch listener for MYET.

Then , onTouch, return TRUE(instread of false).

After that, onTouch, use MYET.setHint(""); This will clear the hint.

Here is the code :

```
 MYET.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                           MYET.setHint(""); 
                return true;
            }
        });
```

note:
If the `setHint("")` does not work, you can use `MYET.setText("");`

Comment: PLEASE READ MY QUESTION !! THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER

Comment: I was posting an answer for the question. You dont have to downvote me because of that.