# Cursor resides in editText position at zero

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

While entering the edit text values using the keypad layout that I have created, the cursor resides at the starting position.The cursor position doesn't moving as per the values entered. Is there any way to implement this.
Code is as follows:

```
String zip;
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int id = v.getId();
                if (id == R.id.button0) {
                    zip = zip + "0";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button1) {
                    zip = zip + "1";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button2) {
                    zip = zip + "2";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button3) {
                    zip = zip + "3";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button4) {
                    zip = zip + "4";
                    //editZip.requestFocus();
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button5) {
                    zip = zip + "5";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button6) {
                    zip = zip + "6";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button7) {
                    zip = zip + "7";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button8) {
                    zip = zip + "8";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.button9) {
                    zip = zip + "9";
                    editZip.setText(zip);
                } else if (id == R.id.buttonDel) {
                    if (zip.length() > 0) {
                        zip = zip.substring(0, zip.length()-1);
                        editZip.setText(zip); 
                    }   
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: you should really use a switch for readability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setSelection(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection%28int%29) to move cursor position.

```
editZip.setSelection(editZip.getText().length());
```

At last into `OnClickListener` code.

---

Some SO references

1. [How to set cursor position in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext)
2. [Place cursor at the end of text in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217378/place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-in-edittext)