# Formatting EditText phone number as user types

Tags: android, formatting, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'd like to edit an `EditText` field content everytime the user types a new character. Basically I want to format a phone number using [`libphonenumber`](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

I implemented a `TextWatcher` that reads the field content and formats it into the phone format. But every time I set the `EditText` text with the formatted string, the watcher is called again, sets the text once more, and it gets stuck in this infinite loop.

What is the best or proper way to edit the text as user types?

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editable.length() > 1) {
        try {
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(editable.toString(), "BR");
            String formatted = phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
            telephone.setText(formatted);
        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
           Log.d("Telefone", "NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful with calling setText method inside TextWatcher. Otherwise you create an infinite loop, because you are always changing the text.

You could try the following an only set the text if it is *really* necessary:

```
if(!telephone.getText().toString().equals(formatted)) {
    telephone.setText(formatted);
}
```

Instead of just:

```
telephone.setText(formatted);
```

That way you should be able to avoid creating an infinite loop

Comment: If I may ask another question, when I change the text, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the text field. How can I make it stay at the end?

Comment: Try this answer about cursor positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8035171/2399024