# Append slash to EditText

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, append

I wrote a TextWatcher for EditText view.
In method

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str = mTxtView.getText().toString();
            if ((str.length() == 2 && len < str.length())) {
                mTxtView.append("/");
            }
        }
```

nothing happend;

Changing

```
mTxtView.append("/");
```

with

```
mTxtView.setText(str+"/");
```

is not suits me, because cursor jumps to 1st position in EditText.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why append("/") isn't working, however you can workaround your second issue with setText by using editText.setSelection(end_position); as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext

Comment: thank you, it works