# focus on previous EditText at RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have some vertical `EditText` in a `RecyclerView`.

when I touch an `EditText` at second half vertical screen. Cursor moving on previous `EditText` and focus on it.

I searched about this and could not find any solution .

please help..

Edit:

i'm clicking an edit text that's in position 10 of recycler view.

but android focuses on edit text that's in position 9

Edit 2 :
my adapter class:

```
public class inputsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<holder> implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    public List<String> paramList,resultList;
    Context mContext;
    boolean doneParam,doneResult;
    public View focusedView;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
    public inputsAdapter(List<String> paramList, List<String> resultList, Context mContext) {
        this.paramList = paramList;
        this.resultList = resultList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.doneParam=false;
        this.doneResult=false;
        this.focusedView=null;
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (mContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.correct_params) );
    }

    @Override
    public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.parameter_row,parent,false);
        return new holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(holder holder, final int position) {
        if(position<paramList.size()){
            holder.paramConst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.paramConst.setTag(position);
            holder.paramEt.setAdapter(adapter);
            holder.paramEt.setText(paramList.get(position));
            holder.addParam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneParam=false;
            holder.paramEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        }else if(position==paramList.size()){
            holder.paramConst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.addParam.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_box_black_24dp));
            holder.addParam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.paramConst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.addParam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(position<resultList.size()){
            holder.resultConst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.resultConst.setTag(position);
            holder.resultEt.setText(resultList.get(position));
            holder.addResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doneResult=false;

        }else if(position==resultList.size()){
            holder.resultConst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.addResult.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_box_black_24dp));
            holder.addResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.resultConst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.addResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(paramList.size()>resultList.size())
            {return paramList.size()+1;}
        else {return resultList.size()+1; }
    }


    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if(b){
            this.focusedView=view;

        }else{
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout= (ConstraintLayout) view.getParent();
            int index= (int) constraintLayout.getTag();
            EditText et= (EditText) view;
            paramList.set(index,et.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    AutoCompleteTextView paramEt,resultEt;
    Button addParam,addResult;
    ConstraintLayout paramConst,resultConst;
    public holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        paramEt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.paramEt);
        resultEt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultEt);
        paramConst=itemView.findViewById(R.id.paramConstraint);
        resultConst=itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultConstraint);
        addParam=itemView.findViewById(R.id.paramAddAfterBtn);
        addResult=itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultAddAfterBtn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cursor position in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext)

Comment: post what you are doing

Comment: it's not.for example :i click edit text in position 10 but cursor focuses on edit text that in position 9

Answer (score 1):

Your `getItemCount` method is returning the wrong value. You don´t need to add a +1 to it. So change your method to the following code and see if it´s solving your problem:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(paramList.size()>resultList.size())
        {return paramList.size();}
    else {return resultList.size(); }
}
```