# How to set cursor position after hint message in TextInputEditText

Tags: android, layout

How can I set the cursor position to the right of the hint message.

entire code is here

```
         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:hint="@string/_254"
                android:inputType="phone"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to use hint text as default text that user need to edit?

Comment: Try this answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53709860/9060917

Comment: Yeah the user can edit

Comment: Your posted answer does not solve what your question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have managed to solve the problem`

**java **

```
final EditText edit = findViewById(R.id.hint);
edit.requestFocus();
edit.setSelection(edit.length()-0);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The use of hint is to prefeed the EditText and when the user typing the hint would be replace by user's entry

Maybe you would like to use the `android:text` instead or you can use the `setSelection()` method for place the cursor at the right position