# TextWatcher class trims space from end when spacebar is pressed and cursor moves to beginning of editText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

Below is my textWatcher class:

```
class MyTextWatcher(private val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        count: Int,
        after: Int
    ) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        before: Int,
        count: Int
    ) {
        val text = editText.text.toString()
        if (text.startsWith(" ")) {
            editText.setText(text.trim())
        }
        else if (text.endsWith(" ")){
            editText.setText(text.trim())
        }
        else if (text == " "){
            editText.setText(text.trim())
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

}
```

**After writing in editText field when i press spacebar in the end of word, editText cursor moves to the beginning of the editText field before 1st letter.**

***What should i do such that when i press spacebar cursor should remain at the same position it should not go at beginning?***

Comment: try `val text = s.toString()` instead of  `val text = editText.text.toString()` and let me know the result.

Comment: @MohammadDerakhshan no it is not working cursor is still going to the beginning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53709860/4467687